# Why do people behave normally when they come across Ted

Tags: ted, ted-2

Ted is famous and most of the people will be aware that a walking talking teddy bear exists in the world but its not normal to come across a walking talking teddy bear in daily life at a public place. It is strange that people are not even excited to see him. Why is that so?

Comment: I dont mind the downvote but it will be good if someonce can explain the reason. It may help to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Its not normal to come across a walking talking teddy bear in daily life at a public place

It's not normal in our reality but it is normal in this *movie universe*

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_(film)#Plot) says<sup>*</sup>

> In 1985, 8-year-old John Bennett is a lonely child living in Norwood, Massachusetts, a suburb of Boston, who wished for his new Christmas gift—a jumbo teddy bear named Ted—to come to life and become his friend. The wish coincides with a shooting star and comes true; **word spread and Ted was briefly a celebrity**.

T**ed has been around for over 25 years and his existence is well known**. Certainly he's unique and one could argue that he should be more of a celebrity but people get blase about such things.

<sup>* Thanks to @BCdotWEB</sup>

In fact, as noted by @Gallifreyan it's stated that

> "Eventually, nobody gives a shit"

Comment: Understood that he is around from last 25 years but people are so neutral that he walks unnoticed even on the busy streets of Manhattan, Boston etc.

Comment: He's not unnoticed...it just that it' snot unnatural to them.

Comment: I think it's actually said by the narrator in the first film: "eventually, nobody gives a shit" (here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbKwJM06fRM)

Comment: @Gallifreyan That's the perfect answer.